# How many types of Yogic practices are there?

Tags: yoga

I have heard about few types of Yogic practices. For example, Hatha Yoga, Kriya Yoga etc. Exactly how many types of Yogic practices are mentioned in our scriptures? Please give references from Scriptures, not from any secondary sources.

I just want to add one clarification. Here I am not using the term Yoga in the spiritual metaphysical sense. For example, Karma Yoga, Gyana Yoga, Bhakti Yoga - these are different paths for metaphysical gainings. Here I am interested in yogic practices (in physical sense), like a form of exercise kinds of activity, that are mentioned in the Yoga branch of Hindu Philosophy.

Comment: @hanugm I have edited the question. I am actually asking about yogic practices under the Yoga branch of Hindu philosophy. I am not talking about different Margas (Gyana marga, Bhakti Marga etc.). The term Yoga is used here in a very specific sense.

Comment: @sv. that question and answer actually talk about yoga in a general sense. For example, Gyan yoga, Karma yoga. Here I am talking about yogic practices under yoga philosophy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 types of Yogas - Mantra Yoga, Hatha Yoga, Laya Yoga and Raj Yoga - Siva Samhita (5.9).[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit about each of them too.

Comment: @Vivikta I would love to do that. But unfortunately, I do not know much about them.